# Resize image captured by camera without crop

Tags: android

If I want to resize the captured image to a fixed height and width(example:2000px*3000px),how can I do that? I don't want to use crop.I just want to save the image in server with a fixed height and width.

This is my code:

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode ==  REQ_CAMERA_IMAGE) {

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           /* int newWidth=(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 622, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int newHeight=(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, newWidth, newHeight, true);*/
            resultIv.setImageBitmap(photo);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            int x=(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 177, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int y=(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 273, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            cropView.of(Uri.fromFile(finalFile)).withAspect(x,y).initialize(ImageType.this);
        }


        public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
       /* ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);*/
        int newWidth=(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 75, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int newHeight=(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 114, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, newWidth,newHeight, false);

     //   Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, newWidth, newHeight, true);
     //   Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage,(int)(inImage.getWidth()*0.9), (int)(inImage.getHeight()*0.9), true);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), resized, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

I have commeneted the code which I have tried.It is not giving the output as  I want.

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: @Sohail Zahid Yes.I have edited the question with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code you can set max/min height and width of an Image but setting where degree is optional for rotation of image pass 0 if don't want to rotate.

```
public static bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        int width = 2000; // - Dimension in pixels
        int height= 2000;  // - Dimension in pixels
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my code what I have tried.Can you please check that.

Comment: When I checked with this,I am getting 518*800 pixels

Comment: public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        int width = 2000; // - Dimension in pixels
        int height= 2000;  // - Dimension in pixels
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, width, height, false);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), resizedBitmap, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

Comment: do the resize after croping of image

Comment: Ok. Now How can I alter this code if I want to resize after cropping image?

Comment: get the bitmap after croping the image and call this method this will give you a image with 2000x2000 then upload this to your server

Answer (score 0):

**Resizing bitmap**

```
 int width = 120;
 int height= 120;
 Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width, height, false);
```

Comment: You are croping  why if you dont want to crop `cropView.of(Uri.fromFile(finalFile)).withAspect(x,y).initialize(ImageType.this);`

Comment: I want to crop in that way where user is not having permission to resize while cropping.So I have used <com.oginotihiro.cropview.CropView> for cropping with fixed height and width.And after cropping I am saving the image in server.

Comment: there is no condition in your code to check weather user has resizing permission or not how you are determining.

Comment: I have tried with your code inside getImageUri() method. when I checked the image dimension in server it was 63*96 pixels.

Comment: I am setting x and y for fixed cropping there with 177 and 273 height and width.Is that creating problem while saving image to server??